# I18n: How to check if a translation key/value pairs is missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the [I18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n). I (am implementing a plugin and) I would like to check *at runtime* if the I18n is missing a translation key/value pairs and, if so, to use a custom string. That is, I have:

```
validates :link_url,
  :format     => {
    :with => REGEX,
    :message  => I18n.t(
      'custom_invalid_format',
      :scope => 'activerecord.errors.messages'
  )
}
```

If in the `.yml` file there is not the following code

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    messages:
      custom_invalid_format: This is the test error message 1
```

I would like to use the `This is the test error message 2`. **Is it possible? If so, how can I make that?**

*BTW*: For performance reasons, is it advisable to check *at runtime* if the translation key/value pairs is present?

Comment: Would something like this be of use?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223806/how-to-use-rails-i18n-fallback-features

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just had the same question and I want to compute an automatic string in case the translation is missing. If I use the `:default` option I have to compute the automatic string every time even when the translation is not missing. So I searched for another solution.

You can add the option `:raise => true` or use `I18n.translate!` instead of `I18n.translate`. If no translation can be found an exception is raised.

```
begin
  I18n.translate!('this.key.should.be.translated', :raise => true) 
rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData
  do_some_resource_eating_text_generation_here
end
```

Answer (score 23):

You could pass a :default parameter to I18n.t:

```
I18n.t :missing, :default => 'Not here'
# => 'Not here'
```

You can read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Answer (score 18):

I don't know how to this at runtime but you can use rake to find it out. You'll have create your own rake task for that. Here's one:

```
namespace :i18n do
  desc "Find and list translation keys that do not exist in all locales"
  task :missing_keys => :environment do

    def collect_keys(scope, translations)
      full_keys = []
      translations.to_a.each do |key, translations|
        new_scope = scope.dup << key
        if translations.is_a?(Hash)
          full_keys += collect_keys(new_scope, translations)
        else
          full_keys << new_scope.join('.')
        end
      end
      return full_keys
    end

    # Make sure we've loaded the translations
    I18n.backend.send(:init_translations)
    puts "#{I18n.available_locales.size} #{I18n.available_locales.size == 1 ? 'locale' : 'locales'} available: #{I18n.available_locales.to_sentence}"

    # Get all keys from all locales
    all_keys = I18n.backend.send(:translations).collect do |check_locale, translations|
      collect_keys([], translations).sort
    end.flatten.uniq
    puts "#{all_keys.size} #{all_keys.size == 1 ? 'unique key' : 'unique keys'} found."

    missing_keys = {}
    all_keys.each do |key|

      I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
        I18n.locale = locale
        begin
          result = I18n.translate(key, :raise => true)
        rescue I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument
          # noop
        rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData
          if missing_keys[key]
            missing_keys[key] << locale
          else
            missing_keys[key] = [locale]
          end
        end
      end
    end
    puts "#{missing_keys.size} #{missing_keys.size == 1 ? 'key is missing' : 'keys are missing'} from one or more locales:"
    missing_keys.keys.sort.each do |key|
      puts "'#{key}': Missing from #{missing_keys[key].join(', ')}"
    end
  end
end
```

put the given in a .rake file in your lib/tasks directory and execute:

```
rake i18n:missing_keys
```

Information source is [here](http://mentalized.net/journal/2009/08/10/find_missing_translations_in_your_rails_application/) and code on github [here](https://github.com/koppen/i18n_missing_keys).

Comment: Your answer doesn't not accomplish what I am looking for, but thank you anyway. Waiting for another answer...

Comment: If you do something like this, note that translation keys may not match up exactly due to different pluralization rules (and so different keys). Fixed here: https://gist.github.com/2994129 (via my http://henrik.nyh.se/2012/07/rails-i18n-tips/)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass variable to the message like `This is the test error message {variable}`

This is possible using variable in language file like below.

```
# app/views/home/index.html.erb
<%=t 'greet_username', :user => "Bill", :message => "Goodbye" %>

# config/locales/en.yml
  en:
     greet_username: "%{message}, %{user}!"
```

More description you can [find here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that isn't what I am looking for (re-read the question, please).