# Configure I18n fallbacks on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, internationalization, i18n-gem

I have tried everything to make the i18n Fallback on Heroku but I couldn't.
I don't want to get the "translation missing messages". It work OK on developement mode.

Please help!

thanks

```
require "i18n/backend/fallbacks"
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
I18n.fallbacks.map(:es => [:en])
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

Comment: According to what I know, to use fallback, you must pass a default value to I18n. See https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/wiki/Fallbacks. If it can't found any value, it will show the the "translation missing messages".

Answer (score 3):

I have this in my application.rb file:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]
```

and I just commented this code in production.rb:

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

and it's working ok for me in heroku.

Comment: Great! Commenting `config.i18n.fallbacks = true` helped!

Answer (score -1):

In config/enviroments/production.rb

```
class Appname::Application.configure do
  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
end
```

[how to use rails i18n fallback features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223806/how-to-use-rails-i18n-fallback-features)