# Rails internationalization - is there better way to keep messages in english?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, i18n-gem

I recently make a decision to translate my tiny rails app with I18n gem as it described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).
While a testing, as it expected, I got a error messages from activerecord and devise:

> translation missing: ru.devise.failure.user.not_found_in_database
>   translation missing: ru.activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.taken

At this moment I know only one way to set up massages with custom locale - simply copy en.yml file which contains messages into my custom ru.yml, but it's weird way.
Maybe I missed something?

Cheers!

Comment: Would the `default` option be a good fit for you ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4244177/919641 . Note that you can also use rails-i18n gem for common translations (https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) and, for devise they provide common translations also (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n)

Comment: And of course you can set up a fallback locale to avoid missing translations http://stackoverflow.com/a/7621851/919641

Comment: I'll post my comments as an answer then, feel free to accept them if you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `default` option ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4244177/919641))

I also advise you to look into the [rails-18n](http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) gem for common translations

Devise provide common translations on [their wiki](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n)

You can also set up a fallback locale to avoid missing translations ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7621851/919641))