# Rails I18n: How to set fallback locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'm on `Rails 4`, and I'm following [how to use rails i18n fallback features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223806/how-to-use-rails-i18n-fallback-features)

My website only has 2 lang, `zh`, and `en`, and I want other language such as `de`, `fr` fallback to `en`, so I set as suggested above:

```
 config.i18n.fallbacks =[:en]
```

But when I visiting `http://localhost:3000/?locale=de` it still reports
`"de" is not a valid locale`. (`locale` for `en` and `zh` works fine)

How can I fix this?

UPDATE: this is how I receive `locale`

```
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `config/application.rb`

```
I18n.config.enforce_available_locales = false
```

Comment: You can also keep the check and do `config.available_locales += [:whatever, :locales]`