# Use scope in distance_of_time_in_words_to_now to use default language [EN]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, translation, rails-i18n

My Rails Application uses internationalization.

In my admin stats I want to display the last log in time of users:

`<td> <%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(user.current_sign_in_at) %> ago </td>`

But rails wants to translate the whole statement and I get the following translation error:

`translation missing: de.datetime.distance_in_words.x_days ago`

How can I tell rails to use the default [EN] language in `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now` ?

Comment: Use fallback https://stackoverflow.com/a/7245792/4758119

Comment: Ah great thanks - that worked. Had to restart the server though.

Comment: hmmm, on localhost everything was fine, on heroku I still get the error and I already restarted the server with `heroku restart`

Comment: did you commit the changes and pushed the code?

Comment: Yes just checked. I am on rails 4.2.6

Comment: maybe  I should put the fallback in `config/environments/production.rb`?

Comment: Yes - that did the trick, I changed `config.i18n.fallbacks = true` to `config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]`

Comment: well the answer said that only ;)

Comment: `config.i18n.fallbacks =[:de, :fr, :en]`